# SQL get values between two times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table in SQL Server (2012),
It contains the following:  (sample data)

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>itemRef(vchar50)</th><th>itemStatus(vchar50)</th><th>statusStart(datetime)</th><th>statusFinish(datetime)</th></tr><tr><td>itemXYZ</td><td>ORDER RECEIVED</td><td>2018-12-10 20:10:18.000</td><td>2018-12-10 22:10:19.000</td></tr><tr style='background-color: #cecece;'><td>itemXYZ</td><td>PICKING</td><td>2018-12-10 22:10:19.000</td><td>2018-12-11 11:14:32.000</td></tr><tr><td>itemXYZ</td><td>PACKING</td><td>2018-12-11 11:14:32.000</td><td>2018-12-11 12:10:53.000</td></tr><tr><td>itemXYZ</td><td>DISPATCH NOTICE</td><td>2018-12-11 12:10:53.000</td><td>2018-12-11 12:10:57.000</td></tr><tr><td>itemXYZ</td><td>AWAITING DISPATCH</td><td>2018-12-11 12:10:57.000</td><td>2018-12-11 12:27:14.000</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I'm trying to run queries against the table that separates days of the week into shifts:

- (Day Shift: Mon - Thurs 8am - 10pm & Fri 8am - 3.30pm)

  ```
  ((DATEPART(dw, statusStart) in (2,3,4,5) and CONVERT(TIME, statusStart)>=''08:00:00'' AND CONVERT(TIME, statusStart) < ''22:00:00'') OR 
  (DATEPART(dw, statusStart) in (5) and CONVERT(TIME, statusStart) >=''08:00:00'' AND CONVERT(TIME,statusStart) < ''15:30:00''))';
  ```
- (Night Shift: Mon - Fri 10pm - 8am)

  ```
  ((DATEPART(dw, statusStart) in (2,3,4,5) and (CONVERT(TIME, statusStart) >=''22:00:00'' OR CONVERT(TIME, statusStart) < ''08:00:00'')))';
  ```
- (Weekend Shift: Fri - Mon 3.30pm - 8am)

  ```
  ((DATEPART(dw, statusStart) in (6,1) OR (DATEPART(dw, statusStart) in (5) and CONVERT(TIME, statusStart) >=''15:30:00'') OR (DATEPART(dw, statusStart) in (2) and CONVERT(TIME, statusStart) <''08:00:00'')))';
  ```

The above is part of a stored procedure - which returns the data correctly except when a itemStatus began before the shift started and finished during the shift - ie the highlighted row in the table above!

If I run a query - select * from table where shift is Day shift - the Picking status will be excluded as it began before Day shift started - 8am

[image: image1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57vkY.jpg)

What I am trying to achieve is that If I run a query - select * from table where shift is Day shift

[image: image2][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lqDc.jpg)

8am becomes the new start time for Picking - 
I could then query - whats the time difference between statusStart and statusFinish where the shift is Day shift and the itemStatus is 'Picking'

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Your query should return all items that start before or during and end during or after the shift? If so, you will want _statusStart_ to be less than or equal to the end of the shift, and you will want _statusFinish_ to be greater than or equal to the beginning of the shift. Or is it more complicated than that? Are you hoping to return only the 8am to 11:14:32am portion of _Picking_? Maybe some IF statements about the edges of the shifts would help then. For example, IF _statusStart_ less than 8am on a weekday, return 8am. Something like that?

Comment: @CardiDeMonacoJr basically I would like to capture anything that occurs between 8am and 10pm. As you can see above 'Picking' started before 8am - image [1]   I'm essentially wondering is there a way to set the start time to 8am - You have got me thinking though. maybe a case when!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might get you in the direction you're looking for...

```
SELECT 
    itemRef,
    itemStatus,
    CASE WHEN CONVERT(TIME, statusStart) >  CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, statusStart)  = 5 THEN '15:30:00' ELSE '22:00:00' END THEN DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, statusFinish)) + CAST('08:00:00' AS DATETIME) ELSE statusStart END AS statusStart,
    statusFinish
FROM #test
WHERE 
   (DATEPART(dw, statusStart) in (2,3,4,5) and CONVERT(TIME, statusStart)>='08:00:00' AND CONVERT(TIME, statusStart) < CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, statusStart)  = 5 THEN '15:30:00' ELSE '22:00:00' END)
   OR (DATEPART(dw, statusFinish) in (2,3,4,5) and CONVERT(TIME, statusFinish)>='08:00:00' AND CONVERT(TIME, statusFinish) < CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, statusStart)  = 5 THEN '15:30:00' ELSE '22:00:00' END)
```

You can test it here: https://rextester.com/TGO17469

Returns these results:

[image]

**UPDATE**
Filtering for "Picking" based on the comment requires a small adjustment to the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE 
   (
       (DATEPART(dw, statusStart) in (2,3,4,5) and CONVERT(TIME, statusStart)>='08:00:00' AND CONVERT(TIME, statusStart) < CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, statusStart)  = 5 THEN '15:30:00' ELSE '22:00:00' END)
       OR (DATEPART(dw, statusFinish) in (2,3,4,5) and CONVERT(TIME, statusFinish)>='08:00:00' AND CONVERT(TIME, statusFinish) < CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, statusStart)  = 5 THEN '15:30:00' ELSE '22:00:00' END)
   )
AND itemStatus = 'Picking'
```

Testable here: https://rextester.com/HXJP15440

Comment: it doesn't work when limiting the results to - AND itemStatus = 'PICKING'

Comment: would something like this have any obvious issues https://rextester.com/WKGGW92570

Comment: No obvious issues, no. Not sure if it matters or not, but if you look at this new sample, I've added a new item where the picking begins at 19:10:19 and when it gets returned it returns as that time, not 8AM. Not sure if that needs to be accounted for or not, but thought I'd throw it out there for consideration - https://rextester.com/HIV31103

Comment: no that's the desired outcome - cheers, now I just have to figure out if it goes beyond 10pm then set the maFinish to 10pm :/

Comment: Something like this one? You can see the itemXYZ ORDER RECEIVED status ends at 22:00:00 - https://rextester.com/WADN38436